# Trying to empty linked list

Tags: c

I'm trying to loop through my linked list and free all the nodes in that list.

The function is supposed to do:

It should free up the space associated with every node in the linked list in the stack, but it should not free up the space associated with the stack structure in memory, but should set the head pointer to NULL.

These are my structs:

```
typedef struct nodeT {
    valueT value;
    struct nodeT* next;
} node;
```

```
typedef struct {
    node* head;
} stack;
```

This is the function I'm having issues with:

```
void ClearStack(stack* s) {
    while ( s ) {
        node* temp = s->head->next;
        free(temp);
    }

    free(s);
}
```

Inside of `s` there are 7 nodes. The program crashes on the second loop and I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: You are not freeing `s->head`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are freeing the `head->next` of `s` and then it is `NULL` for the next loop.  You should rearrange the order to this:

```
void ClearStack(stack* s) {
    while ( s->head ) {
        node* temp = s->head;
        s->head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }

    free(s);
}
```

EDIT: An explanation for the `while` condition fix: The loop should be finished executing when all the nodes inside `s` are free, not when `s` itself is free. As for the change inside the loop, you store the head in temp, set the new head to the `head->next` node and then free `temp`.  That way the list is always getting shortened from the front and will finish when `head->next` is null.

Comment: @user3121023 It would be better to do a sanity check before the loop rather than checking that `s` isn't null on every iteration.  Especially since `s` gets freed after the while loop, so even if the loop doesn't iterate at all because `s` is NULL, it would still crash when `s` is subsequently freed.

Comment: You fixed the while-loop condition in the solution code, but you should also mention it in your explanation.

Comment: @user3121023 Huh.  Right you are.

Comment: `s` is *not* NULL for the rest of the loop. free tells the system that the memory is no longer in use. It does not change the value of the pointer to NULL or anything else. `s` points to the same memory it always did, because it is never assigned to.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: but it should not free up the space associated with the stack structure in memory, but should set the head pointer to NULL..  I.E. this statement: `free s;` should not be  there

Answer (score 2):

Let's step through what the code is doing.  Suppose we start with this list:

```
a = { .value = 42, .next = &b }
b = { .value = 0, .next = NULL }
lst = { .head = &a };
```

And let's assume that a is at memory 0x8000, b is at memory 0x8008, and lst is at memory 0x8010 just to get some concrete values for the pointers.  Now we call ClearStack(&lst).

```
while (s)                    # s is 0x8010, so this is true

node *temp = s->head->next;  # temp is now 0x8008 (&b).

free(temp);                  # We free the memory.  temp is still 0x8008, but you don't  
                             # own that memory anymore.

while (s)                    # back to the top of the loop. s is still 0x8010. still true.

node *temp = s->head->next;  # temp is assigned to 0x8008 (&b) again.

free(temp);                  # You already freed that memory; freeing memory you don't 
                             # own is undefined. The program is likely to crash here (*)
```

You never change s or s->head, so the program just loops through the first element in the list over and over until it crashes.

(*) Although it doesn't have to crash; undefined behavior means it can do *anything*, including working as you expect for awhile just to mess with your head.